# Como gerar código antes de inserir dados no banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso gerar um código que seja igual ao `id` que será auto-incrementado no banco de dados. Será uma rotina que verifica o ultimo `id` gerado e gera um código que será o `id` posterior antes da inserção dos dados.

Por exemplo:

Se o ultimo `id` foi o `id 2`, a rotina vai gerar o código 3 que é o `id` que será auto-incrementado quando inseridos os dados no banco.

Como posso conseguir esse resultado com PHP e MySQL?

Comment: Se for no banco, basta criar um campo inteiro com `auto_increment`, que o banco faz isso automaticamente,

Answer (score 6):

Segue a *query* para obter o próximo ID:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'nome_da_tabela'
AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Ou uma destas:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM nome_da_base_de_dados LIKE 'nome_da_tabela';
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM nome_da_base_de_dados WHERE Name='nome_da_tabela';
```

Note que estas *queries* são bem específicas, servindo provavelmente só no MySQL mesmo. A opção com `SHOW TABLE STATUS` **retorna várias colunas**, entre elas o próximo auto-incremento.

Uma alternativa seria você dar um UPDATE na própria linha que acabou de inserir, usando a coluna `id` + 1, o que dá na mesma de obter o `last_insert_id()`.

De qualquer forma, vale dizer que provavelmente esta solução que você está procurando cedo ou tarde vai dar problema, seja por falha na inserção, dois usuários tentando inserir quase ao mesmo tempo, ou mesmo o simples desencontro de dados na hora de alguma remoção.

Eu não posso afirmar isto, pois você não deu detalhes do que está fazendo, mas pela pergunta inicial, tenho um leve *feeling* de que, seja lá o que está tentando fazer, talvez tenha outras maneiras de se resolver.

Comment: Vou testa essa query, aparentemente parece que vai resolver o meu problema.

Comment: Conseguir de outra forma, vou postar o código fonte.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir solucionar o problema com o seguinte código:

**OPÇÃO MENOS CRIATIVA**

```
public function geraCod(){
        //Conexão
        $db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'usbw', 'atendimento');
        //Seleciona o último código
        $new_cod = $db->query('SELECT MAX(cli_cod) as id FROM clientes');
        $new_cod = $new_cod[0];     

        $new_cod =  ($new_cod['id'] + 1);
        echo str_pad($new_cod, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

**SEGUNDA OPÇÃO:**

```
public function geraCod(){
        $db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'usbw', 'atendimento');
        $cols = Array ("clientes");
        $new_cod = $db->rawQuery("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM atendimento WHERE Name =  ?", $cols);
        $new_cod = $new_cod[0];     

        echo $new_cod['Auto_increment'];
    }
```

Comment: O problema disso é que se você deletar o maior registro, o número vai repetir. O auto-incremento no MySQL é sequencial, e não depende do MAX(). Exemplo: se você gera o registro de ID 30 e deleta este registro, sua função vai gerar 30 de novo, e o auto-increment vai manter o 31.

Comment: Vc tem razão, vou editar o código da resposta.

Comment: Igor, isso retorna o mesmo resultado da solução do Bacco.. Ambos, conforme o Bacco mencionou, tem o risco de colisão. Se um outro usuário acessar no mesmo tempo e gerar o ID antes, a coisa vai conflitar.  E esse tipo de situação , pela natureza do pocesso, tem uma probabilidade muito grande.

Comment: Existe alguma solução para quando estiver vários usuários conectados eu consiga gerar um código referente ao próximo id que será inserido?

Comment: Até o momento eu só conseguir chegar a esse resultado.

Comment: Só uma observação, somar + 1 não é uma boa ideia, pois pode apresentar um erro, se dois usuários incluírem dados de forma assíncrona. Além disso, se vc der refresh várias vezes, vai incluir uma soma absurda no seu banco.