# Como pego o id autoincrement sem estar registrado?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Como pego o id que é autoincrement sem o item estar cadastrado no banco de dados?
Ou eu vou ter que faze 2 processo, cadastrar primeiro o post, depois cadastrar o post na categoria ?

Eu to com um sistema de cadastrar posts aqui, e as tabelas estão separadas para mim poder cadastrar o mesmo post em varias categorias:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela: Produtos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela: Categorias**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela de relação: Produtos ~ Categorias**

[image: Tabela de relação entre produtos e categorias]

Código PHP para cadastrar o post:

```
$cadastrarItem = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_mark (name_mark, description_mark, keywords, att_mark, image_mark, link) VALUES (:title, :description, :keywords, NOW(), :img, :linkitem)");
                $cadastrarItem->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $cadastrarItem->bindParam(':img', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $cadastrarItem->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $cadastrarItem->bindParam(':keywords', $tags, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $cadastrarItem->bindParam(':linkitem', $linkitem, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $verificaItens = $conexao->prepare("SELECT name_mark FROM tb_mark WHERE name_mark=:title");
                $verificaItens->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $verificaItens->execute();

                if($verificaItens->rowCount() == 0)
                {
                    $cadastrarItem->execute();
                    echo '<script language= "javascript">
                    location.href="/admin_include_brand/register_item";
                    </script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script language= "javascript">
                    location.href="/admin_include_brand/register_error";
                    </script>';
                }
```

E seria basicamente isso para mim cadastrar a categoria na tabela:

```
    $cadastrarItemCategoria = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_category_itens (id_item, id_category) VALUES (:id_item, :id_category)");
// id_item = 'id' da tabela produtos
// id_category = 'id' da tabela categorias
    $cadastrarItemCategoria->bindParam(':id_item', $id_item, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $cadastrarItemCategoria->bindParam(':id_category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar o próximo ID a ser inserido?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45634/como-pegar-o-pr%c3%b3ximo-id-a-ser-inserido)

Comment: Caso ainda queira mesmo prosseguir, aqui vai um tópico relacionado, mas leia o link acima antes desse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99347/como-gerar-c%C3%B3digo-antes-de-inserir-dados-no-banco/99348#99348

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rapaz eu tive esse problemas esses dias

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nomedatabela'
```

aqui como utilizei

```
try {
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nomedatabela' ";  
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->fetch();
$proximoID = $resultado['Auto_increment'];  // a chave esta aqui
 } catch (Exception $ex) {
 echo $ex->getMessage();
}
echo $proximoID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um método usando o `information_schema`.

A construção do MySQL será:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = <NOME DA TABELA> AND table_schema = <NOME DO BANCO DE DADOS>
```

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

// Dados necessários:
$nome_tabela = 'tabela';
$nome_banco = '';

// Se deixar o $nome_banco em branco isto irá usar a função DATABASE():
$nome_banco = ($nome_banco != '') ? "'".$nome_banco."'" : "DATABASE()";

// MYSQLI! Irá efetuar a query:
$id = $mysqli->query("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '$nome_tabela' AND table_schema = $nome_banco");

// Irá pegar e exibir o AUTO_INCREMENT:
$id = $id->fetch_array();
$id = $id['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
echo $id;

?>
```